# AWS Lambda boto3 error when using rds execute_statement with parameter formatRecordsAs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

Has anyone encountered this Error when using the Lambda with boto3 rds execute_statement( )?

```
[ERROR] ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "formatRecordsAs", must be one of: continueAfterTimeout, database, includeResultMetadata, parameters, resourceArn, resultSetOptions, schema, secretArn, sql, transactionId
```

I have been using vs code to develop lambda functions locally and it works fine when using boto3:rds execute_statement( ) with the "formatRecordsAs" parameter. Here is what I have tested successful locally:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = execute_statement(sql)['formattedRecords']
    df = pd.read_json(response)
    df_string = df.to_string()
    print(df_string)


def execute_statement(sql):
    response = db.rds_client.execute_statement(
        secretArn = db.db_secret_arn,
        database = db.db_name,
        resourceArn = db.db_resource_arn,
        sql = sql,
        formatRecordsAs='JSON'
        )
    return response
```

I was able to pass in a string as sql statement (specifically SELECT where returning response in json format is needed) using the above code on my local vs code editor. I get records returned in json format as expected.
However once I paste my code to lambda, I get everything else working as expected except "formatRecordsAs".(see error code above)

When formatRecordsAs = 'JSON' is omitted, I then get successful response as I would in other settings unformatted. But I really need the returned data to be formatted in json.

To my understanding, somehow according to the error message, AWS Lambda doesn't register formatRecordsAs as a valid parameter but accept all other parameters listed in the documentation.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: can you confirm that whatever calls `lambda_handler` is below `execute_statement` given that it would not be defined otherwise.  or a min reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Actually, during each run, aws lambda will call lambda_handler directly so it makes lambda_handler( ) act like a "main" function. I am sure that whenever I am testing locally, I will write a separate call at the end, otherwise, no function will be invoked.  And the code works both locally, and in the console without the formatRecordsAs parameter being passed.

Comment: @D.L this is a minimal reproducible example for an AWS Lambda function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boto3 in a lambda function **is not full** nor it is the latest version. Thus its quite common to run into the issues you report with invalid arguments, etc.

You have to bundle full boto3 with your function, for example using a layer.

Comment: Are you saying the full version of boto3 is not included in the runtime environment? Do you have a citation for that? That has NOT been my understanding or experience. However I agree that this could be a version issue because the latest version of boto3 is not included.

Comment: @MarkB Yes. I don't have link for that (its undocumented), but boto3 in lambda is not full. There are many issues like the OP has with boto3 in lambda.

Comment: The issue above is almost certainly because Lambda provides Boto3 version 1.20.32 at this time, while the latest version is 1.25.1. It's just a version difference, not some sort of limited "not full" version of boto3.

Comment: @MarkB it can be old version or cropped version in general . Either way OP has to bundle newest and full version himself.

Comment: It definitely will not be a cropped version.